# Problema al hacer paginación con php

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo paginación con php para mi buscador, hasta ahora todo va bien, estoy usando mysql pero cuando estoy intentando darle función a el botón de anterior un error relacionado a la variable 'pagina', estoy usando el método GET y los botones para cambiar de página en página me funcionan bien. Los datos de mi consulta se muestra correctamente, todo me funciona excepto que me marca el error para el botón de regresar a la anterior página.

Este es todo mi código.

```
<?php

    include_once 'conection.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM imagenesAn';
    $sentencia = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->execute();

    $resultado = $sentencia->fetchALL();

    $articulos_x_pagina = 10+1;
    //contar artículos de nuestra base de datos
    $total_articulos_db = $sentencia->rowCount();
    $paginas = $total_articulos_db / 10;
    $paginas = ceil($paginas);

    $salida = "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenesAn WHERE nombre NOT LIKE '' ORDER By id DESC LIMIT $articulos_x_pagina ";

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
        $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenesAn WHERE Id LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR nombre_imagen OR registro LIKE '%$q%'";
    }


    if ($resultado AND $resultado->num_rows>0) {
        $salida.="<table class='table table-borderless tabla table-responsive-sm' style='width: 92%; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 40px; text-align: center;'>
                <thead class='jeder'>
                    <tr class='text-primary'>
                    <th scope='col text-primary'>ID</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Nombre</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody class='cuerpo'>";
        //var_dump($resultado);
            foreach($resultado as $articulo): 
            $salida.="
                <tr>
                        <td style='text-align: center;'>".$articulo['id']."</td>
                        <td style='text-align: center;'>".$articulo['nombre']."</td>
                        <td style='text-align: center;'><a href='diagnostico?id=". $articulo['id']."'><i class='fas fa-file-medical-alt fa-2x' style='color: #c80000'></i></a></td>

                    </tr>";
            endforeach;?>

                <div class="contenedorPaginacion">
                    <nav aria-label="Paginación" class="paginacion">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a class="page-link" 
                                href="buscador.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">
                                    Anterior
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <?php for($i = 0;$i<$paginas;$i++){ ?>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a
                                href="buscador.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1?>" class="page-link">
                                <?php echo $i+1?>
                            </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php }?>


                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a href="#" class="page-link">Siguiente</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>


            <?php
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";
    }else{
        $salida.="<p class='parrafo' style='margin-left: 10px;'>No se encontraron resultados similares a su busqueda</p>";
    }


    echo $salida;

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8odPbC8Yhk&t=481s

El eror que me marca es este:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: pagina in C:\Proyecto\buscar.php on line 76 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006422336{main}( )...\buscar.php:0 -1"> Anterior
```

Comment: Hola, ¿estás seguro de que estás enviándole al archivo un parámetro por $_GET llamado página?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres, ¿cómo se hace eso?

Comment: Te recomendaria, controlarlo todo por Javascript.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta librería @Jesús https://datatables.net/ Con respecto al parámetro $_GET trata de poner todo el código posible en tu pregunta para poder analizar juntos el error.

Comment: Ya coloqué todo mi código, espero me puedas ayudar, gracias.